# Switch between youTube & Vimeo sources w/ jQuery

Tags: jquery, iframe, youtube, vimeo

I have three working links to youTube. The user can click text blocks and the URL updates inside the iFrame. The problem is that, I can't get Vimeo or Twitch to play in the fourth link. I've tried everything I can think of. I removed the Vimeo and Twitch links because they're long and cumbersome. I'm ok using any video for now. Any suggestions?

```
<div class="videoHolder">
    <div id="descriptions">
    <div id= "vid1Link" class="vidDetails">
    <div id="text"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/6ZDL5M0-DbM" target="someFrame">Video 1</a></div>
</div>

<div id= "vid2Link" class="vidDetails">
    <div id="text"><p><a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PL13657A9E281737CD" target="someFrame">Video 2</a></div>
</div>

<div id= "vid3Link" class="vidDetails">
    <div id="text"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/YVzkL8GuqKs" target="someFrame">Video 3</a></div>
</div>

<div id= "vid4Link" class="vidDetails">
    <div id="text" class="link4"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/YVzkL8GuqKs" target="someFrame">Video 4</a></div>

</div>
</div>
<div class="videoPlayer">       
    <iframe name="someFrame" id="someFrame" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0"></iframe> 
</div>
</div>

<script>

$('.link4').click(function(){
  // ??
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/fg4svu0r/1/embedded/result/

You just have to provide correct embeddable links to all resources. No JS required.

```
<div class="videoHolder">
    <div id="descriptions">
    <div id= "vid1Link" class="vidDetails">
    <div id="text"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6ZDL5M0-DbM" target="someFrame">Video 1</a></div>
</div>

<div id= "vid2Link" class="vidDetails">
    <div id="text"><p><a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PL13657A9E281737CD" target="someFrame">Video 2</a></div>
</div>

<div id= "vid3Link" class="vidDetails">
    <div id="text"><a href="https://www.twitch.tv/gsl/embed" target="someFrame">Video 3 - TWITCH</a></div>
</div>

<div id= "vid4Link" class="vidDetails">
    <div id="text" class="link4"><a href="https://player.vimeo.com/video/100902779?color=cc3232&api=1" target="someFrame">Video 4 - VIMEO</a></div>

</div>
</div>
<div class="videoPlayer">       
    <iframe name="someFrame" id="someFrame" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0"></iframe> 
</div>
</div>
```